# IIS Application Request Routing Server Farm Settings

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, routes, windows-server

On an IIS server with Application Request Routing, new server farms to be routed to can be added by right-clicking Server Farms -> Create Server Farm.

This will pop up a dialog where the settings for the server farm can be entered. I did not manage to find a way to edit or view these settings after they are accepted in the Create-Serverfarms-dialog.

My question is therefore: How can I edit the target-url, http-port and https-port settings of a server farm outside of the create-serverfarm dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the command line to do so.

For example, lets say we have a `Server Farm` called `test` with one application server `www.example.com` in it:

[image: www.example.com]

All the following commands need to be run in the `%windir%\system32\inetsrv` directory unless you have it in your `PATH`.
To change the `target-url` of the application server to `www.google.com`, use:

```
appcmd.exe set config /section:webFarms /"[name='test'].[address='www.example.com']".address:www.google.com
```

You can change any parameters the way you would do it with the dialog (and even more).
To get the list of parameters you can use with the command line:

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:webFarms -?
```

And particularly the section you seem to be interested by:

[image: interesting settings]

And finally, to view the current config of your server farm:

```
appcmd.exe list config /section:webFarms
```

Should get you something like:

[image: config]

**References:**

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/define-and-configure-an-application-request-routing-server-farm

**Update:**

You may [generate](https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/automating-arr-configuration/) PowerShell script from IIS Manager.

[image: IIS Manager 1]

[image: IIS Manager 2]

[Web Server (IIS) Administration Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx)

Also, you may edit `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` file manually.